# HLSL: Memory coalescing with structured buffers

Tags: memory, buffer, hlsl, coalescing

I'm currently working on an HLSL shader that is limited by global memory bandwidth. I need to coalesce as much memory as possible in each memory transaction. Based on the guidelines from NVIDIA for CUDA and OpenCL (DirectCompute documentation is quite lacking), the largest memory transaction size for compute capability 2.0 is 128 bytes, while the largest word that can be accessed is 16 bytes. Global memory accesses can be coalesced when the data being accessed by the threads in a warp fall into the same 128 byte segment. With this in mind, wouldn't structured buffers be detrimental for memory coalescing if the structure is larger than 16 bytes?

Suppose you have a structure of two float4's, call them A and B. You can access either A or B, but not both in a single memory transaction for an instruction issued in a non-divergent warp. The layout of the memory would look like ABABABAB. If you're trying to read consecutive structures into shared memory, wouldn't memory bandwidth be wasted by storing the data in this manner? For example, you can only access the A elements, but the hardware coalesces the memory transaction so it reads in 128 bytes of consecutive data, half of which is the B elements. Essentially, you're wasting half of your memory bandwidth. Wouldn't it be better to store the data like AAAABBBB, which is a structure of buffers instead of a buffer of structures? Or is this handled by the L1 cache, where the B elements are cached so you can access them faster when the next instruction is to read in the B elements? The only other solution would be to have even numbered threads access the A elements, while odd numbered elements access the B elements.

If memory bandwidth is indeed wasted, I don't see why anyone would use structured buffers other than for convenience. Hopefully I explained this well enough so someone could understand. I would ask this on the NVIDIA developer forums, but I think they're still down. Visual Studio keeps crashing when I try to run the NVIDIA Nsight frame profiler, so it's difficult to see how the memory bandwidth is affected by changes in how the data is stored. P.S., has anyone been able to successfuly run the NVIDIA Nsight frame profiler?

Comment: Nsight shouldn't be crashing Visual Studio. Which version of Nsight and Visual Studio are you using?